# create web part that looks like out-of-the box sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have to create a web part that displays all site collections under the root site. The requirements are:

1) the web part should look like the out-of-the box list
2) should display two columns, Title and created
3) Should be able to sort the columns
4) display a maximum of items between 5 and 10

I thought to use List view web part or XSLT List View Web Part, but since I don't have experience in sharepoint I thought it will be really great if anyone of you has got an example, and please let me know which one is best to use.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`SPGridView` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spgridview.aspx) does exactly what you need.

The blog post [SPGridView and SPMenuField: Displaying custom data through SharePoint lists](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powlo/archive/2007/02/25/displaying-custom-data-through-sharepoint-lists-using-spgridview-and-spmenufield.aspx) provides a good tutorial.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) if it was useful for you.